# Accessing IEnumerable Model values outside the foreach at Razor view

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
@foreach (var company in employee.Companies)
{
    <li>Company - @Html.DisplayFor(m => company.Name)</li> // Inside Loop
}
```

How can i access the data without using the for loop for the first element.

```
<li>Company - @Html.DisplayFor()</li> // Outside Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to display the list item when the company list is empty:

```
@model ...
@{
    var firstCompany = Model.Employee.Companies.FirstOrDefault();
}

@if (firstCompany != null)
{
    <li>
        Company - @Html.DisplayFor(x => firstCompany.Name)
    </li>
}
```

Unless you have crazy templates for the company name string, otherwise why not just do:

```
@model ...
@{
    var firstCompany = Model.Employee.Companies.FirstOrDefault();
}

@if (firstCompany != null)
{
    <li>
        Company - @firstCompany.Name
    </li>
}
```